# I want to write a kernel driver program where when a file is created I need to be notified

Tags: c++, winapi, kernel, driver, msdn

I used the reference of [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43586/File-System-Filter-Driver-Tutorial) project where it creates a handler for IRP_MJ_CREATE. which displays all the files which are created or opened the system.
The documentation of IRP_MJ_CREATE is this:

> The I/O Manager sends an IRP_MJ_CREATE request when a new file or
> directory is being created, or when an existing file, device,
> directory, or volume is being opened.
>
> Normally this IRP is sent on behalf of a user-mode application that
> has called a Microsoft Win32 function such as CreateFile or on behalf
> of a kernel-mode component that has called a function such as
> IoCreateFile, IoCreateFileSpecifyDeviceObjectHint, ZwCreateFile, or
> ZwOpenFile.
>
> If the create request is completed successfully, the application or
> kernel-mode component receives a handle to the file object.

This program below prints all the files or volumes which are opened, created.

main.c

```
    for (i = 0; i <= IRP_MJ_MAXIMUM_FUNCTION; ++i) 
    {
        DriverObject->MajorFunction[i] = FsFilterDispatchPassThrough;
    }
//creating handle for IRP_MJ_CREATE.
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE] = FsFilterDispatchCreate;
```

```
// IRP_MJ_CREATE IRP Handler

NTSTATUS FsFilterDispatchCreate(
    __in PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject,
    __in PIRP           Irp
    )
{
    PFILE_OBJECT pFileObject = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp)->FileObject;
    
    
    DbgPrint("%wZ\n", &pFileObject->FileName);

    return FsFilterDispatchPassThrough(DeviceObject, Irp);
}
```

I just need the driver to print only when a file or directory is created.

Comment: You need to know what happened with the irp after you pass it, so don't simply return `FsFilterDispatchPassThrough`. Instead you should do similar operation but after `IoCallDriver` check the `IoStatus->Information` of the irp for what happend (for this case check for `FILE_CREATED`).

Comment: I printed the information in Irp->Iostatus->Information it has only null value. is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention you should not allowing it to free the irp using completion routine. Check out this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/different-ways-of-handling-irps-cheat-sheet. I think scenario 2 is good for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter driver is being called before the actual file system driver. However you want to check the result after the file system driver handled the irp. according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/irp-mj-create) article, you can simply check `irp->IoStatus.Information == FILE_CREATED`.

Now you only need to let the file system driver know that you have more processing to do with the irp, so it won't call `IoCompleteRequest` and free the irp. To do so we can use scenario 2 out of the [Cheat Sheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/different-ways-of-handling-irps-cheat-sheet). It will end up something like this:

```
NTSTATUS
CompletionRoutine_2(
    IN PDEVICE_OBJECT   DeviceObject,
    IN PIRP             Irp,
    IN PVOID            Context
    )
{ 
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DeviceObject);

  if (Irp->PendingReturned == TRUE) {
    // 
    // You will set the event only if the lower driver has returned
    // STATUS_PENDING earlier. This optimization removes the need to
    // call KeSetEvent unnecessarily and improves performance because the
    // system does not have to acquire an internal lock.  
    // 
    KeSetEvent ((PKEVENT) Context, IO_NO_INCREMENT, FALSE);
  }
  // This is the only status you can return. 
  return STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED;  
} 

NTSTATUS
FsFilterDispatchCreate(
    IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject,
    IN PIRP Irp
    )
{
    KEVENT   event;
    NTSTATUS status;

    KeInitializeEvent(&event, NotificationEvent, FALSE);

    // 
    // You are setting completion routine, so you must copy
    // current stack location to the next. You cannot skip a location
    // here.
    // 
    IoCopyCurrentIrpStackLocationToNext(Irp);

    IoSetCompletionRoutine(Irp,
                           CompletionRoutine_2,
                           &event,
                           TRUE,
                           TRUE,
                           TRUE
                           );

    PFSFILTER_DEVICE_EXTENSION pDevExt = (PFSFILTER_DEVICE_EXTENSION)DeviceObject->DeviceExtension;
    status = IoCallDriver(pDevExt->AttachedToDeviceObject, Irp);

    if (status == STATUS_PENDING) {
       KeWaitForSingleObject(&event,
                             Executive, // WaitReason
                             KernelMode, // must be Kernelmode to prevent the stack getting paged out
                             FALSE,
                             NULL // indefinite wait
                             );
       status = Irp->IoStatus.Status;
    }

    // Your logic
    if (Irp->IoStatus.Information == FILE_CREATED) {
        PFILE_OBJECT pFileObject = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp)->FileObject;
        DbgPrint("%wZ\n", &pFileObject->FileName);
    }


    // 
    // Because you stopped the completion of the IRP in the CompletionRoutine
    // by returning STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED, you must call
    // IoCompleteRequest here.
    // 
    IoCompleteRequest (Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
    return status;
}
```

When using the [example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43586/File-System-Filter-Driver-Tutorial) you based on, you can simply change the function to this.

Comment: This is usually what was returned to you from calling to `IoAttachDeviceToDeviceStack`. I see that in the example you based on they are doing it differently from the device object itself (the object pointer they use in `IoCallDriver`). Never tried it this way but maybe it will work as well (if you do it in this way let me know if it worked)...

Comment: So I've compiled it with the example you used and it's works for me. They indeed save the top device in the device object so you need to simply use it. I've edited to solution to work "out of the box" with the example. Let me know if there are more problems.

Comment: Note that you should call `IoCallDriver` not on your `DriverObject` but the device you attached to (note how this is done in the solution)! This is basing on that you are using the example you attached. Otherwise you should get the top device according to what you use. This what will cause the irp to pass to the actual driver you are filtering. If your project is copied from the example just do the changes as I wrote should work.

Comment: I took the example you used and changed the dispatch method exactly with the solution I've posted (with declaring the completion routine before).

Comment: Your error seems like resources leaks. Try to restart the VM you test on (or revert to clen state)

Comment: Regarding the not using of `DeviceObject` it's vecause you compile with warnings as error. You can simply add in the beginning `UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DeviceObject)`. Regarding the BSOD I'll try to understand when I'll be near a computer but it worked for me.

Comment: I updated the solution to compileimmediately. Please try again and if the crqsh happens again provide the crash dump or more information from a debugger to help understand the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure how to give you the zip. I'll walk you with what I've done - the project of the example is very old so to avoid dealing with this I've created a new "Empty WDM" project and copy all the ".c" and ".h" files to it, Disabled spectre mitigations, deleted the auto ".inf" file and it was good to go. What are the errors you get? Maybe I had a problem when copied the solution...

Comment: You the best.. it worked!!! I was editing with old project so It was giving me bsod when I created a new project it worked completely fine!! THANKSSSSS SOO MUCHHH.... and I deleted the comments where those were not actual errors soo.. Thanks again!!! I'm so happy

Comment: Great! Really happy to help :)
(and of course don't forget to accept the answer)

Comment: Is there any way to get the handle of the file and send the Handle to an user application???

Comment: You are really not supposed to do these kind of things. Why not passing the path to the user and let it open a handle?

Comment: Techniquely speaking you can open the handle yourself (using the jernel api), then you need to open somehow a handle to the caller application and convert the handle to a usermode handle (probably with DuplicateHandle). But again this is not something you are suppose to do so there are probably many pitfulls and potential problems...

Comment: When a installer installs a application and creates new files I will get the handle of the newly created Files using the kernel Driver and pass it to user space and then with the handle i will find the process id and parent process id

Comment: The result I'm trying to achieve is finding which process created a new file.